# Getting a ColorPicker value

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I am using the

> Chiralcode ColorPicker for Android

This is a nuget package that I have installed to create a ColorPicker. Now I have done that and I want to get the selected color. To do that I need to do this:

```
SelectedColor = ColorPickerDialog.GetColor();
```

This returns me an integer with a value something like this: `-61145`. But how can I use this value to create a rgb string or a hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors sometimes represented as Int. You need to decode the raw number. Try using that:

```
var color = ColorPickerDialog.GetColor();   
int A = (color >> 24) & 0xff; // or color >>> 24
int R = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
int G = (color >>  8) & 0xff;
int B = (color      ) & 0xff;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what A is?

Comment: It's the Alpha component of a color int.Take a look at the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space).

Comment: Thank you so much!